# What is the Gmail MX server port?

Tags: email, smtp

I know that the Gmail MX (Mail Exchanger) server is at `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`, but I can't find the port.
Port `25` worked for me earlier, but now it seems to have broken. Every time I try to connect, the connection times out. Is there a `TLS/SSL` port that I could use instead?

Also, is there a default `TLS/SSL` port for all MX servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/lJZECWhPBFM, I am probably not able to connect due to a lack of a DNS address.

Thanks to everyone for helping me get to that realization.

Answer (score 0):

It is 587(TLS), and 465(SSL). You can take a look at [the google document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, but this is for `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: What are you going to achieve? The mentioned server seems to be open at port 25. You may want to check the [similar issue in Google Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/lJZECWhPBFM)

Comment: I'm trying to make an SMTP *server*.

Comment: Use port 25 with STARTTLS if you need encryption